# Javascript asp.net c# multi objet pass to Js code file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have code on html page and it is working:

```
document.getElementById('<%=IdOstan.ClientID %>').options.length = 0;
```

it is part of a function. Object is found and code run.
But if I move code to a seperate js file, then call the file using :

```
<script src="../../../../Script/AjaxCall.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then object is not found. My conclusion was that Object on the same file can be found with calling document.getElementById , but it is not true about object passed to Js, and seems normal.
I have tried to pass object while calling JS function like this :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="IdLand" runat="server" onchange="UpdateOstan(this);" 
     DataTextField="NameLand" DataValueField="IdLand" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
     AutoPostBack="false">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and it also works. But I need to pass a second object too I have tried :

```
onchange="UpdateOstan(this, IdsecondObj);"
```

which failed, also this

```
onchange="UpdateOstan(this, document.getElementById('IdSecondObject'));"
```

not working.
So pleas let me know how to pass html object to Javascript which is not on the same page.
**I don't want to use jQuery files as helper,at all.**
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hidden input to store ID value of your IdOStan.ClientID and get that value for id name from your external javascript and then you can access that object.

```
<input id="MyHidden" value="<%=IdOstan.ClientID %>" />
```

In external JS file.

```
var id = document.getElementById('MyHidden').value;
var IdOstan = document.getElementById(id);
```

Now IdOstan is the object you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jonas T, but I prefer to find a way to pass object from Html code to javascript as said above. Do you know how?

Comment: The problem is that `<%= IdOstan.ClientID %>` is an ASP code evaluation section that is only translated during the processing of a View.  If you put that into a JS file that is NOT being handled as an ASP page, it will result in invalid code.  All `<% %>` blocks MUST go into the ASP pages themselves, not into script files or other resources loaded by the browser.

Comment: Thanks Corey, but do you mean that it is not possible to pass an html object to an external javascript file? I think there must be some method , so I am looking for syntax.

Comment: Jonas T answer is a method to solve problem for one Object, but I need to call function several time with other objects, so it must be possible to pass object by Id to JS file and inside the JS file do rest of work

Comment: I don't think you can pass the objects by reference from other objects' event, Ahmad. Only 'this' keyword allows you to pass the current object by reference to the function. The only way you can pass is string (id of the object) and create the object using document.getElementById(id) function.